# OrderedCounter returning RecursionError

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, method-resolution-order

I was trying out the Ordered Counter based on the talk given by **Raymond Hettinger** in [PyCon 2015](https://youtu.be/EiOglTERPEo?t=1655). I trying to do the same with python 3.6.8

```
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict

class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}({})".format(self.__class__.__name__,
                               OrderedCounter(self))

    def __reduce__(self):
        return self.__class__, (OrderedCounter(self),)
```

On trying this code

```
ox = OrderedCounter("abrac")
ox
```

The traceback is as follows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/py30539GwP", line 8, in __repr__
  File "/tmp/py30539GwP", line 8, in __repr__
  File "/tmp/py30539GwP", line 8, in __repr__
  [Previous line repeated 194 more times]
  File "/home/blue/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/collections/__init__.py", line 535, in __init__
    self.update(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/blue/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/collections/__init__.py", line 614, in update
    if isinstance(iterable, Mapping):
  File "/home/blue/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/abc.py", line 184, in __instancecheck__
    if subclass in cls._abc_cache:
  File "/home/blue/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/_weakrefset.py", line 72, in __contains__
    wr = ref(item)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Could someone please tell me the possible cause and solution? If I've missed out anything, over- or under-emphasized a specific point, let me know in the comments.

Comment: All recursion has to terminate at some point. When will yours end?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp okay what shall I do to end the recursion?

Comment: You may want to read the [blog post](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) that video is based on. Note, though, that you are creating another instance of `OrderedCounter` in your definition of `__repr__`; Hettinger created an instance of `OrderedDict`.

Comment: @chepner I am so sorry, that's just typo. should I delete the question